# Labeling oriented surface using Asymptote

Tags: align, asymptote

[image]I am  trying to label an angle on the plane normal to an arbitrary vector in three dimensions. I tried  to  multiply the label `$\omega t$` by `XY()`  or combinations of XY(), XZ() and YZ() without success. Any sugestions?

```
settings.render=6;
settings.outformat="pdf";
usepackage("bm");
// import modules
import graph3;
import three;
import solids;
// overall settings
currentprojection=orthographic(.25,.5,.1);
viewportmargin=(10,10);
size(6cm);
currentlight=((3,3,0));
// variable parameters
real r=1;
real radio=sqrt(1-(cos(pi/8))^2);
real theta1=0, theta2=112.5;
real phi1=0, phi2=65;
// axes
xaxis3("$\bm{e}_1$",0,r,black,Arrow3);
yaxis3("$\bm{e}_2$",0,r,black,Arrow3);
zaxis3("$\bm{e}_3$",0,r,black,Arrow3);

//This draws a rotated frame theta=pi/8, varphi=pi/8
triple x3=(0.3535533905932738,0.1464466094067262,0.9238795325112868);
triple x2=(-0.3826834323650898,0.9238795325112868,0);
triple x1=(0.8535533905932738,0.3535533905932738,-0.3826834323650898);
triple centro=cos(pi/8)*x3;
triple spinproyxy=(-0.8741514406663723,0.4032814824381883,0.2705980500730985);
draw(O--x2,black+dashed,Arrow3,L=Label("$\bm{e}_2'$",position=EndPoint));
draw(O--x1,black+dashed,Arrow3,L=Label("$\bm{e}_1'$",position=EndPoint));
draw(O--x3, black+dashed,Arrow3,L=Label("$\bm{e}_3'$", position=EndPoint,SE));

//Circle[![enter image description here][1]][1]
path3 mycircleB=circle(c=O,r=1,normal=x3);
draw(surface(mycircleB),gray+opacity(.3));
draw(mycircleB,black+opacity(.3));
//This draws the angle ometa t
draw(arc(c=O,x1*.2,x2*.2, normal=x3), black+linewidth(.5pt),Arrow3(TeXHead2),L=Label("XY()*$\Large\omega t$", position=MidPoint,S));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I do not know how you arrive at your expressions for `x1` and so on. In the standard conventions of the Particle Data Group, the orthogonal matrix formed by `(x1,x2,x3)^T` has the mixing angles `theta1=pi/8`, which is consistent with your comments, and `theta2=3*pi/8`, which is only almost consistent with your comment. However, the conventions may differ. In any case, if I introduce a minus sign and transform `XY()` by `rotate(22.5,Y)*rotate(-22.5,Z)` I obtain a result that looks reasonable. This minus sign could be a convention issue. Or, what is more likely, there could be better rotation parameters. It would help quite a bit if you provided more details on how you computed `(x1,x2,x3)`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{asypictureB}
\standaloneenv{asypicture}
\begin{document}
\begin{asypicture}{name=disc}
settings.outformat = "pdf";
settings.prc = false;
settings.render = 0;
usepackage("bm");
// import modules
import graph3;
import three;
import solids;
// overall settings
currentprojection=orthographic(.25,.5,.1);
viewportmargin=(10,10);
size(6cm);
currentlight=((3,3,0));
// variable parameters
real r=1;
real radio=sqrt(1-(cos(pi/8))^2);
real theta1=0, theta2=112.5;
real phi1=0, phi2=65;
// axes
xaxis3("$\bm{e}_1$",0,r,black,Arrow3);
yaxis3("$\bm{e}_2$",0,r,black,Arrow3);
zaxis3("$\bm{e}_3$",0,r,black,Arrow3);

//This draws a rotated frame theta=pi/8, varphi=pi/8
triple x3=(0.3535533905932738,0.1464466094067262,0.9238795325112868);
triple x2=(-0.3826834323650898,0.9238795325112868,0);
triple x1=(0.8535533905932738,0.3535533905932738,-0.3826834323650898);
triple centro=cos(pi/8)*x3;
triple spinproyxy=(-0.8741514406663723,0.4032814824381883,0.2705980500730985);
draw(O--x2,black+dashed,Arrow3,L=Label("$\bm{e}_2'$",position=EndPoint));
draw(O--x1,black+dashed,Arrow3,L=Label("$\bm{e}_1'$",position=EndPoint));
draw(O--x3, black+dashed,Arrow3,L=Label("$\bm{e}_3'$", position=EndPoint,SE));

//Circle
path3 mycircleB=circle(c=O,r=1,normal=x3);
draw(surface(mycircleB),gray+opacity(.3));
draw(mycircleB,black+opacity(.3));
//This draws the angle omega t
draw(arc(c=O,x1*.2,x2*.2, normal=x3), black+linewidth(.5pt),Arrow3(TeXHead2), 
L=Label(rotate(22.5,Y)*rotate(-22.5,Z)*XY()*"$\Large\omega t$", position=MidPoint,S));
\end{asypicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]